# I want to set a thread inside getView method how should i do it?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

the code of getView method is this:

```java
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

            LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
            View v;

            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.rowdetails, parent, false);

            TextView _tvname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            ImageView _ivimg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivimg);

            Car_setget c = new Car_setget();
            c = arrlist.get(position);          

            _tvname.setText(c.getname());

            //loader.displayImage(c.getimg(), _ivimg, op, null);

            ImageDownloader task = new ImageDownloader();
            try {

            Bitmap image = task.execute(c.getimg()).get();
            _ivimg.setImageBitmap(image);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       

            return v;
        }
    }


//ImageDownloader.java
  public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                return bitmap;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
  }
```

How may I solve this? I want to create a new thread inside that thread I want to declare the whole body of `getView` Method. Is it possible or not? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 (Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //  your code
                Toast.makeText(magContext, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```